# Individual origins doesn't work with transform tool along normals for edges

Tags: normals

Results for median point and individual origins transform along a normal axis yields same results for edges, but not faces.

See video:

[image: gif]

The expected behavior would be a different result, specifically a translation along the Z axis of each individual edge's normal,  but Blender can apparently only do faces (the extrude individuals special tool)?

Comment: What were you expecting to see? Individual Origins doesn't provide individual results if edited geometry is connected. I don't really see any difference between moving connected edges and connected faces with Indivual Origins on.

Comment: I guess I was expecting the behavior that "extrude region" provides, only for translating edges.

I had to resort to using a plugin now, which can be found here and only works with entered decimal numbers (no sliding with the mouse unfortunately):

https://github.com/marciodrosa/FanPlugin